# PYROCMS call plugin from controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyro

this is my plugin function.

```
class Plugin_name extends Plugin
   function test(){
     return '1';
   }
}
```

i want to use this function in Controller file.

how can i call plugin function in Controller.

thank you.

Comment: plugins are created to be called from views not from controller. If you need something you can create a helper function for this

Comment: @RenishKhunt are you still using CI pyrocms ?

Comment: @AkshayHegde No, I am not using Pyrocms

Comment: @RenishKhunt ok old question I thought of posting answer once, later seen timestamp almost 5 year old post, and CI pyrocms is expired.